# How to update List as a parameter in another Object in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, arraylist, realm

I have two classes where one of them is as a variable in second class. It looks like that:

```
class Dogs: Object {
    dynamic var name: String?
    dynamic var age: String?
}

class Person: Object {
    dynamic var owner: String?
    var dogs: List<Dogs>() //I would like to UPDATE one of element from this list
}
```

and now, I would like to update one element from this `List<Dogs>` but I have a still problem with it. I try to do achieve goal doing it:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var person: Person?
    ...

    func update(){
        let updatedDog = Dogs()
        updatedDog.name = "Tinky"
        updatedDog.age = "12"
        try! realm.write {
        person.dogs[0] =  updatedDog
        }
    }
}
```

this solution doesn't work. Do you have any idea how can I update it?

Comment: I think `var dogs = List<Dog>()` has to be a `let dogs...` (by the Realm documentation at least). Take a look at [`LinkingObjects`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships)

Answer (score 1):

In your `ViewController` you need to grab the actual Dog you're updating and update it in a write block.

```
Realm().write {
   updatingDog.name = "Tinky"
   updatingDog.age = 12
}
// use `updatingDog` as normal
```

## https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#updating-objects